# Django Celery installation Error

Tags: django, celery

I'm been trying to install celery for a couple of days and the problem , I'm facing is . when I try to do manage.py syncd . I get the error message  .

```
C:\o\17\mysite>manage.py syncdb
Error: No module named djcelery
```

When I already successfully installed the celery using easy_install

```
 C:\o\17\mysite>easy_install django-celery
 Searching for django-celery
 Best match: django-celery 3.0.17
 Processing django_celery-3.0.17-py2.6.egg
 django-celery 3.0.17 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
 Installing djcelerymon script to C:\Python26\Scripts
 Installing djcelerymon-script.py script to C:\Python26\Scripts
 Installing djcelerymon.exe script to C:\Python26\Scripts
 Installing djcelerymon.exe.manifest script to C:\Python26\Scripts

 Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django_celery-3.0.17-py2.6.egg
      Processing dependencies for django-celery
 Finished processing dependencies for django-celery
```

I already set up my broker which is the django database i'm using.

BROKER_URL = 'django://'

I added djcelery to installed_app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'pet',
        'kombu.transport.django',
'djcelery ',
)
```

I also added the following lines to my setting.py

```
 import djcelery
 djcelery.setup_loader()
```

I have experience in installing django plugins before , I just don't understand why this won't let me syncdb at cmd

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with a space char at the end of `djcelery` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Try to remove it and run `syncdb` again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'pet',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'djcelery ',
)
```